# How do I get the maximum object of a group by criteria (the entire object, not a property of it)

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get the maximum object of an `IGrouping`, by some criteria, however so far I cannot seem to find an overload that will allow me to return an entire object within the group

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>() 
{ 
     new Player() { Name = "Peyton Manning", Age = 36, Position = "QB", Salary = 19000000 },
     new Player() { Name = "Tom Brady", Age = 35, Position = "QB", Salary = 18400000 },
     new Player() { Name = "Drew Brees", Age = 34, Position = "QB", Salary = 21000000 },
     new Player() { Name = "Randy Moss", Age = 35, Position = "WR", Salary = 7000000 },
     new Player() { Name = "Marvin Harrison", Age = 38, Position = "WR", Salary = 11000000 },
     new Player() { Name = "Demaryius Thomas", Age = 23, Position = "WR", Salary = 5000000 },
     new Player() { Name = "Ryan Clady", Age = 26, Position = "OT", Salary = 10000000 },
};
```

I'd like to write a query that returns a resultset which I can enumerate over like this:

```
foreach(Player player in highestPaidPlayers) 
{
      Console.WriteLine("The highest paid {0} is {1}, who is being paid {2}", player.Position, player.Name, player.Salary);
}
```

So far this is as far as I got:

```
var playersGroupedByPosition = players
    .GroupBy(p => p.Position)
    .Select(g => g.Max(p => p.Salary));
```

But this will only give me a list of the highest salaries (eg a list of integers). There doesn't seem to be an overload for `Max` that lets me return a `Player` object from an `IGrouping` other than `Max()`, which relies on an object to implement `IComparable`.

My LINQ is a little weak so I haven't figured out how to write a sub-query to get the maximum entry of a group and return it to the outer select, but is there a more straightforward way to do this?

I've seen solutions that reference using a third party library [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) (and its custom operator `MaxBy`) but I do not want to go that route (yet) unless it is not possible to do with the existing set of query operators - and if not, I would like to understand the limitation of the existing operators preventing this from being done in a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Solution using nested "subselect"*

**Expression syntax solution:**

```
var highestPaidPlayers = players.GroupBy(p => p.Position)
                                 .Select(x => x.Where(p => p.Salary == x.Max(m => m.Salary)).First());
```

**Query syntax solution:**

```
var highestPaidPlayers = from pl in players
                         group pl by pl.Position
                         into g
                             let max = g.Max(x => x.Salary)
                             let maxPl = g.Where(x => x.Salary == max).First()
                             select maxPl;
```

Try on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/I2Aftm).

Answer (score 4):

I think with `ToList` and `OrderBy` you can avoid using third party code:

```
IEnumerable<Player> highestPaidPlayers = players.GroupBy(p => p.Position)
    .Select(g => g.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.Salary).Last());
```